Fargate task CannotPullContainerError failed to unpack image on snapshotter overlayfs failed to get stream processor for application/vnd.in-toto+json
I have a stack configured and deployed with AWS CDK
As part of that stack I have a Fargate task
It has worked in the past but today when I run it I get:

"StoppedReason": "CannotPullContainerError: ref pull has been retried 1 time(s): failed to unpack image on snapshotter overlayfs: failed to extract layer sha256:c02342326b04a05fa0fc4c703c4aaa8ffb46cc0f2eda269c4a0dee53c8296182: failed to get stream processor for application/vnd.in-toto+json: no processor for media-type: unknown"

I have had issue with corrupted lambda layer in the past so I suspect some combination of deleting stuff and redeploying will fix it
But also sometimes cryptic errors can be due to something apparently unrelated in application level
So would love some insight into what causes this error and if it's my fault somehow

seems like a bug in CDK https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/30258
